# SXA 1.6 SOLR SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException unknown field

Tags: sxa, solr

In Sitecore 8.2.6 the following error occurs:

```
WARN [Index=sitecore_master_index] Crawler : AddRecursive DoItemAdd failed - {93F413F7-09AF-4E67-B0C4-45D501DD042C}
Exception: SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException
Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">15</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">ERROR: [doc=sitecore://master/{333bba18-dfd4-4efc-9b74-70fdbb2f5c31}?lang=en&amp;ver=1&amp;ndx=sitecore_master_index] unknown field 'location_tm'</str><int name="code">400</int></lst>
</response>

Source: SolrNet
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.PostStream(String relativeUrl, String contentType, Stream content, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Post(String relativeUrl, String s)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer`1.SendAndParseHeader(ISolrCommand cmd)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrBatchUpdateContext.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 batch)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrBatchUpdateContext.AddDocument(Object itemToAdd, IExecutionContext[] executionContexts)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexOperations.ApplyPermissionsThenIndex(IProviderUpdateContext context, IIndexable version)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.DoAdd(IProviderUpdateContext context, SitecoreIndexableItem indexable)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.HierarchicalDataCrawler`1.CrawlItem(T indexable, IProviderUpdateContext context, CrawlState`1 state)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
Source: System
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at HttpWebAdapters.Adapters.HttpWebRequestAdapter.GetResponse()
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.GetResponse(IHttpWebRequest request)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.PostStream(String relativeUrl, String contentType, Stream content, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
```

When using SXA 1.6 after following the instructions on https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/walkthrough_setting_up_solr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is embedded in the installation guide of SXA 1.6 found here: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator/16/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator_16_Initial_Release.aspx#

To resolve the default indexing the following needs to be added to the schema.xml file:

```
<dynamicField name="*_tm" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_rpt" type="location_rpt" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

Comment: If you will be using Showcase project then it might be needed to also include such field for the Solr schema on 8.2:
`<dynamicField name="*_t_pl" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />`